# Window functions (LAG) with a very specific filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table that contains the status of units we are monitoring reported throughout the day. I've made a much simplified version of this table below.

| ID | Unit | Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10:01 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 10:03 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 10:04 | 5 |
| 4 | A | 10:06 | 1 |
| 5 | B | 10:09 | 4 |
| 6 | B | 10:10 | 4 |
| 7 | A | 10:11 | 2 |
| 8 | A | 10:18 | 2 |
| 9 | B | 10:21 | 4 |
| 10 | A | 10:25 | 2 |

I am provided with a list of IDs for which I need to retrieve the corresponding data **plus** the status of the same unit in it's previous 2 status updates.

For example, if I'm given ID `8`, I need to return:

| Unit | Time | Status | Status_lag1 | Status_lag2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10:18 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

My problem isn't with using the lag function, that's fine. The issue is that if I apply the filter by ID in the same statement, I'm not applying the lag function over the whole table.

```sql
SELECT  Unit,
        Time,
        Status,
        LAG(Status, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Time) AS Status_lag1,
        LAG(STATUS, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Time) AS Status_lag2
FROM    mydata
WHERE ID = 8;
```

But when I do this correctly with a subquery – first doing the lag on the whole table, then applying my ID filter – it's quite slow (it's a large table).

```sql
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
    SELECT  Unit,
            Time,
            Status,
            LAG(Status, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Time) AS Status_lag1,
            LAG(STATUS, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Time) AS Status_lag2
    FROM    mydata
) sub
WHERE sub.ID = 8;
```

Any alternative approaches I'm not thinking of that would improve performance? I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: do you have an index on unit,time, status columns?

Comment: Yes, there's an index on unit and time. Normally queries using these fields run quickly. There's none on the status field (there's actually around 20 different types of statuses reported, so it doesn't make sense to index all of these).

Comment: It matters if your query can use index scan only to produce the result.

Answer (score 2):

> I am provided with a list of IDs for which I need to retrieve the
> corresponding data plus the status of the same unit in it's previous 2
> status updates. ... doing the lag on the whole table, then applying my ID filter – it's quite slow (it's a large table)

One way (assuming list of `2` and `8` for example purposes) would be

```
SELECT md1.Unit,
       md1.Time,
       md1.Status,
       md1.ID,
       oa.Status_lag1,
       oa.Status_lag2
FROM   mydata md1
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Status END) Status_lag1,
                           MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Status END) Status_lag2
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY md2.Time DESC) AS RN,
                                         Status
                            FROM   mydata md2
                            WHERE  md1.Unit = md2.Unit
                                   AND md2.Time < md1.Time
                            ORDER  BY md2.Time DESC) t) oa
WHERE  md1.ID IN ( 2, 8 )
```

For the example above this only reads the 5 rows neccessary to calculate the result (assumes an index on `id` and one on `mydata(Unit, TIME) INCLUDE (Status)`)

[image]

i.e. it reads the row for `id=2` and then the one preceding row with the same Unit (as only one exists) and it reads the row for `id=8` and then the two preceding rows with the same Unit as that.

This should be much less resource intensive if the table is large and you are only interested in a few rows. You'd need to do some testing to find the number of list elements at which it becomes quicker to just scan the whole table rather than do the correlated seek.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an answer to my own questions. Moving the subquery into a temp table took the execution time from over 1 hour to a few seconds:

```sql
SELECT  Unit,
        Time,
        Status,
        LAG(Status, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Time) AS Status_lag1,
        LAG(STATUS, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Time) AS Status_lag2
INTO    #LaggedTable
FROM    mydata;

SELECT  *
FROM    #LaggedTable
WHERE   sub.ID = 8;
```

I'll have to dig into the execution plan to figure out what's the actual difference here.

Comment: "a few seconds" still sounds slow as at the end of the day it only has to read three rows